# Preg_match_all counter?

Tags: php, preg-match-all

```
    <?
    echo "Begin Function=";

    echo "<br>";

    $text = "2lyve: this is: 8475978474957845 948594: jfhdhfkd: just the 2lyve:          beginning:";
    function getTrends($text)
    {
        $subject = $text;
        $pattern ='/(\w+:)/Ui';
        preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches);

        foreach($matches[1] as $value)
        {

            print $value."<br>";

        }

    }

    getTrends($text);
    ?>
```

The result will be:

```
Begin Function=

2lyve:

is:

948594:

jfhdhfkd:

2lyve:

beginning:
```

How do I count how many times each result is returned and rank it? Also, how to I import these results into a sql database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP actually has a specific function for this purpose.

[array_count_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php)

Your code could be changed to

```
<?php
echo "Begin Function=";

echo "<br>";

$text = "2lyve: this is: 8475978474957845 948594: jfhdhfkd: just the 2lyve:          beginning:";
function getTrends($text)
{
    $subject = $text;
    $pattern ='/(\w+:)/Ui';
    preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches);

    $findings = array_count_values($matches[1]);

    foreach($findings as $value=>$occ)
    {
        print $value."<br>";
    }

}

getTrends($text);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare an array `$map = array();` in the start of your function, and then in the place of

```
 print $value."<br>";
```

put

```
if(isset($map[$value])) {
    $map[$value]++;
} else {
    $map[$value] = 1;
}
```

Comment: thanks. I've also tweaked it a little to print out in a clean format, but i'm still trying to rank them by number of occurrences